# How can I apply newly created files when a conflict arises in a git stash apply/pop

Tags: git

I have a stash that contains completely new files and some files with modifications. When I try to apply/pop this stash I get merge conflicts in some of the modified files which are expected but the newly created files in the stash are not applied/re-created. Can I tell git to do that somehow? I don't want to have to commit my resolved conflicts and then try apply it again just to get my new files.

It's like git stash --include-untracked but for applying/popping :-)